# VBA for MS Word: is there a way to make a vertical selection programmatically?

Tags: vba, ms-word, selection

Is there a possible way, in VBA for MS Word, to make a vertical selection? I mean: is it possible to simulate the behavior of the keys Shift+Alt+Selection (by mouse) in a MS Word VBA routine?

Comment: Why do you need to select anything?  You should be working with `Range` objects, not the `Selection` object.

Comment: Ok, but the same problem happens in Range Object (or not?)...
Can we set a vertical range? I mean: in a single step, without using loops?

Comment: I've never tried it, but you could check out `Range.Orientation = wdTextOrientationVertical`.

Comment: First: thank you for the answer!
I have tried your suggestion.
In result, the whole text was turned rigth, by 90 degrees. I am not sure if this will work. I guess it will not.

Comment: LOL.  I guess now I know what *that* does. I poked around in the object model a bit and didn't see much there that looked like it supported vertical ranges. I am curious now though...

Comment: What about using `SendKeys` to simulate keypresses? `SendKeys "+%"` should pretend you've pressed Shift + ALT. More info here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-sendkeys-method-excel

Comment: Thank you, Mr JF. I will try it. When I do it, if I remember, I will put the results here.

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

I find this in2007 Word Developer Reference - Selection.ColumnSelectMode Property

```
With Selection
    .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
    .ColumnSelectMode = True
    .MoveRight Unit:=wdWord, Count:=10, Extend:=wdExtend
    .MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=20, Extend:=wdExtend
    .Copy
    .ColumnSelectMode = False
End With
```

Find it is working.